# favicon.ico passed as url param in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm starting to learn Node.

I am trying to make a RESTful API for a books app with MySQL, so in my Books.js file I have the following code:
(I am using esm to enable import/exports)

```
import express from 'express';
import mysqlConnection from '../database';
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM book', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(!err){
            res.json(rows);
        } else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res)=> {
    const {id} = req.params;
    console.log('id is:',id);
    mysqlConnection.query(`SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn ='${id}'`, (err, rows, fields)=> {
        if(!err){
            res.json(rows);
        } else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
})

export default router;
```

And when I go to "http://localhost:3000/123-456-789-13" for example, I get this as logs in the console:

```
server started!
connected to DB!
id is: 123-456-789-13
id is: favicon.ico
```

It's not failing but I'm surprised to see this... Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is automatically requesting `/favicon.ico` to try to get a thumbnail to represent the website.

But, you have a top level wildcard route with:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res)=> { ...});
```

which matches EVERYTHING at the top level, including the request for `/favicon.ico`.  In general, top level wildcard routes like this are a source of trouble because they allow for NO other top level routes anywhere on your site because they match all top level URLs.  Not only do they match things like `/favicon.ico`, but it will also match `/robots.txt` that search engines may request and it conflicts with you adding other top level routes in the future.

In general, it is recommended that you  provide some resource name first such as:

```
router.get('/book/:id', (req, res)=> { ...});
```

Then, you won't have any of this conflict with other top level routes.